# Python- How to import DecisionTree Classifier from sklearn.tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

1. May I know how to import `DecisionTreeClassifier` from `sklearn.tree` as there is an error shown:
   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`
2. Also, every time when I want to import functions like `pandas`, I need to `pip install` them which is time-consuming. Is there any other methods to avoid installing each time for new importing function? p.s. I have downloaded `anaconda` already, but not sure if it could work.
   [image]

Comment: "every time when I want to import ... I need to pip install them" - this shouldn't happen. The entire point of installing packages is to have them available without installing each time. The error with sklearn happens because Scikit-Learn is not installed: `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: If you are using `conda`, you may need to use it rather than `pip`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

Just Re-install Anaconda with the latest version and use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

music_d=pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X=music_d.drop(columns=['genre'])
y=music_d['genre']


model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
prediction=model.predict([[21,1],[22,0]])
prediction
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as well. I installed `sklearn` using pip install and it gave that error but it worked when I installed `scikit-learn` instead.

You need to install the package using `pip install -U scikit-learn` for windows. [Refer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) for other platforms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the package Sklearn

Comment: OP already imports from `sklearn.tree`. This answer therefore is either useless, or severely underexplained.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).